# box shadow left position using percent value

Tags: css

how can I use percent value in box-shadow property?

for example this one

```
box-shadow: -25% 0 0 #000;
```

chrome log said it invalid value. is it possible to do so? or should i use javascript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `box-shadow` property does not support percentages, but you can achieve a similar effect using a pseudo-element. There are some limitations to this technique, see the comments.

**Example:**

```css
.shadow {
    background: #DDDDDD;
    padding: 1em;
    width: 100px;
    border: solid 1px #999999;
    position: relative;/*Positioning required.*/
}
.shadow:before {
    content: '';
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    z-index: -1;/*Put the shadow behind.*/
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);/*Give the shadow a fill.*/
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);/*The spread value must be greater than or equal to the blur.*/
}
```

```html
<div class="shadow">shadow 50% off center.</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

No you can't.

According to W3C spec on [**box-shadow**](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-background/#box-shadow), it only accept `Distance Unit type <length>` as the value:

> ```
> <shadow> = inset? && <length>{2,4} && <color>?
> ```

While `<percentage>` is a sub type of `Numeric Data Types`, not part of `<length>`. See W3C spec on [**Values and Units**](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-values/#percentages).

You can use js to calculate, or consider a fixed value.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible with viewport-width and viewport-height values.

Example: `box-shadow: -25vw 0 0 #000;` 

That are % from the screen height and width.

Answer (score 0):

applying percentage won't work. However, you can use `vw` and  `vw` which stand for viewport width and height.

`box-shadow: <center-x> <center-y> <blur size> <blur-offset> <blur-color>`
`box-shzdow: -25vw 0 0 0#000;`

Answer (score 0):

You can use as vw and vh
vh = 1/100th of the viewport's height or 1% of the height of the containing block 
vw = 1/100th of the viewport's width or 1% of the width of the containing block 
vmin and vmax = 1/100th of viewport dimensions are minimum or maximum whichever ones used for 
 The viewport percentage lengths are relative to the size of the initial containing block 

In your case if you want box-shadow to be in % then you will have to consider it with respect to the viewport lengths

Code sample 
`box-shadow: 20vw 0 0 #000;`

 
If you want shadow with other dimensions set, i.e.  Top bottom left and right you can try out this one 
`box-shadow : 15vw 10vh 10vh 5vh #000;`